# Win 7 auto restart upon startup logo - Safe mode works - disabling all startup items/services not working

Tags: windows-7

- Ran sfc /scannow in safe mode - no problems
- chkdsk /r /f c: long scan - no problems found - didn't fix issue
- within safe mode , msconfig - disabled all items , services, etc, still auto restarting on normal mode
- safe mode (and with networking) works no problem.
- Start up repair using Win 7 media "....couldn't repair your PC"
- "last known good config" same problem.
- Restored all registry files from 'regback' folder (month old) from recovery console cmd.
- memory test all OK
- removed GPU and only using onboard video. no change.
- nothing in eventlog (Windows 7 doesn't finish starting)
- SSD drive 100% with no bad sectors using surface scan (according to HD Sentinal)

This suddenly started happening after a power outage - computer was idle and not in use - no recent installed apps or updates.

What else could be the problem?

Anything else I can try to salvage this Windows installation?
** I also realize Windows 7 is out of support - This is our media server which only runs plex and Emby and I don't Windows 10 on it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is left is
[How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

As described in the above link, use an ISO of exactly the same Service Pack level as
the currently installed version. You may do so from Safe mode
(which is the only mode that works anyway).

If this does not work, there is the possibility of a hardware problem.
I hope that the computer was protected against power outage with a UPS or at least
a surge protector.

Comment: @Tom G11 I agree, can be a bad RAM module caused by a power outage. I had a power outage which blew, not the module, but the slot on the motherboard for the RAM.